# Firefox throwing too complex error on compiling long words against the regex

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I have a regex as below:

```
var str="checkedchec  ";
var patt=/.*(?:\w+|\S)*\s+(or|and|not|xnot|near|near\d+|onear|onear\d+|title\:|ingress\:|\?|\*|\^|sourceid\:|author\\:|url\:|country\:)\s+.*/i;

var newStr = str.split(patt);

var result=patt.test(str);
```

The above regex works fine mostly but when I have a character longer then 11 characters it gives "expression too complex" except on Mozilla firefox. It works fine on IE and Chrome.

Comment: By "Mozilla" do you mean Firefox or the really, really ancient Mozilla suite?

Answer (score 6):

Your regex runs into [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). You have alternating parts in it that can match the same thing (for example, every character matched by `\w` can also be matched by `\S`, and by the preceding `.*`) so the regex engine has to try oodles of permutations before declaring failure. RegexBuddy for example aborts the match attempt after 1 million steps of the regex engine, and Firefox is obviously doing the same (sensible) thing.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Changing the regex to

```
/.*\s+(or|and|not|xnot|near|near\d+|onear|onear\d+|title:|ingress:|\?|\*|\^|sourceid:|author:|url:|country:)\s+.*/i
```

speeds up the match a lot (now it's only 408 steps until the regex engine can declare failure).

Comment: +1, but I would remove the `.*` from both ends, too.  Actually, I'd do a lot more than that, but the `.*` absolutely doesn't belong there. ☺

Comment: @Alan Moore, I agree that there is a lot more to be done here, and I usually would have removed the `.*`s too, but he might have wanted to capture all lines that contain one of those keywords. Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your regexp can match in multiple ways.

It works if you change `\w+` to `\w`. It is followed by `*` so why do you put a `+` here?

```
/.*(?:\w|\S)*\s+(or|and|not|xnot|near|near\d+|onear|onear\d+|title\:|ingress\:|\?|\*|\^|sourceid\:|author\\:|url\:|country\:)\s+.*/i
```